# How can I use a 2.6.36 kernel in Maverick?

Tags: 10.10, kernel

When I was using Lucid I noticed they had a backport ppa for kernels but they don't have one for Maverick.  I am currently using Maverick in Generic-PAE mode and was wondering what is the easiest way to upgrade the kernel to 2.6.36 with generic-pae?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The backports kernels are only officially available for the previous LTS release; currently this is Lucid (10.04 LTS).  Maverick (10.10) is not an LTS and therefore will not receive backported kernels.

Backports of the as yet unreleased development release are built and made available in the [kernel team PPA](http://www.launchpad.net/~kernel-ppa/+archive/ppa) to allow testing.  Again these are made available for Lucid (10.04 LTS) only.  It is expected that people on a non-LTS release will be able to update to the next release once it is finalised and released formally.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would probably be to email the Ubuntu Kernel Team and ask that they include the `-generic-pae` flavor when they build the mainline maverick kernels. Best place for that would be *kernel-team@lists.ubuntu.com*.

Answer (score 2):

For the mainline 2.6.36 download the kernel from [the Kernel Team's mainline builds](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.36-maverick/) and install, e.g. with a `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`. I'm not sure if this has PAE enabled, though.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't have PAE in the mainline builds.